# Should I put comma after an if-clause inside a that-clause?

Tags: commas

On an academic paper, I wrote the following sentence.

> This equation implies *that* if an agent exploits the former factor, its investment provides a positive profit.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that the comma after an if-clause is grammatically required. Is this rule still valid even inside a that-clause?

Comment: The rule of comma usage doesn't change just because it's inside a "that" clause. The comma is still required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that comma is still required.

If you're concerned that it might be confusing to have a comma in the middle of a *that*-clause like that, then — don't worry, your sentence is fine as-is.

But if you prefer, it would also be totally fine to set off the *if*-clause with commas on *both* sides:

> This equation implies that, if an agent exploits the former factor, its investment provides a positive profit.